# Running Instrumentation Tests in Emulator vs Physical Device

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, asynchronous, testing

I have a test that calls a function with an API call which expects a response, this function has a successHandler and a failureHandler. Normally, I would expect the test to wait for the successHandler or failureHandler before finishing, but that's not always the case.

**When I run the test on an emulator (Pixel 4a API 30):** The function is called, and it waits for the response of either the successHandler or failureHandler, as expected, and then the respective handler called either makes the test pass or fail.

**When I run the tests on a physical device (Samsung Galaxy S7):** The function is called, but the test does not wait for the success or failure handler, so the test succeeds because the handlers that decide if the tests fails or passes are not accessed in time.

If I put the thread to sleep for 5 seconds the handlers are accessed, so it's a matter of async waiting. Just not sure why it waits for the handlers on the emulator but on the physical device it does not.

Keep in mind, the test was ran on @UiThreadTest

Comment: Can you share your test code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.